# How do I setup Security Groups for Amazon RDS (non VPC)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, database-connection

I've successfully launched an Amazon RDS instance (non VPC!) in the Ireland region. Now I need to set the Security Group settings, but these are not present in my console when selecting Ireland. When selecting Virginia the "Security Groups" item shows up in the left menu, but not when selecting Ireland. After digging through Google for hours it seems I need to setup the Security Groups through Amazon EC2. This seems weird to me because I don't need EC2, my app will not be hosted at Amazon (for now). Anyways, creating the Security Groups in EC2 doesn't change anything in my Amazon RDS console, I still can't find the Security Groups settings item in the left nav and thus cannot set CIDR/IP to 0.0.0.0/0.

Comment: "I don't need EC2" ... except, of course, for the fact that RDS instances run in EC2.  First question, I think, is how did you manage to set up a non-VPC RDS instance in Ireland?  I see the same behavior between Virginia and Ireland, but if I try to provision an RDS instance in Ireland, I also can't choose "Not in VPC" like I can in Virginia.  I don't have an explanation for that part either, but if you had to jump through hoops to launch the instance, the real problem may be that you should not actually have been able to provision a non-VPC RDS instance in Ireland at all.  Thoughts?

Comment: The main RDS page in the console tells you which platforms your account supports, in each region.  Mine says "EC2 VPC" in Virginia and "VPC" in Ireland, which explains the discrepancy in the behavior.  There isn't any reason not to use VPC, of course, so I'm curious why you said "(Non VPC!)" as if this were significant.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Michael. It's clear now that I've created an Ireland instance using VPC (because there is no way around like you say + I double checked and I did). I've created a Virginia instance first selecting non-VPC which made me think I did the same creating the instance for Ireland.